# Align a specific character in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have two strings like `"Name | RollNo"` and `"Hostel | Room"`. `Name`, `RollNo`, `Hostel`, and `Room` vary according to `Students`. I want these two in adjacent lines with `|` aligned at the center in both cases.

Specifically, I am trying to create a dialog box for a list view.

My expected output:

```
                                 Raj | 123
                             Hostel1 | 23
```

Here `|` is exactly in the center of the line.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: A visual representation of your expected output would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be so kind to give more context to your issue so as to have a much better understanding. With that being said, I'd suggest to have a look at [DataTable](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/datatable-in-flutter-9242b4a19e67). It might be what you're looking for :)